# from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Predicate

Tags: python, eclipse, jython, monkeyrunner

I could not run monkeyrunner from eclipse eventhough i have set the python interpreter as mentioned in [this](http://fclef.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/using-android-monkeyrunner-from-eclipse-both-in-windows-and-linux/) blog.

I still get this classDefFoundError when the import statement is executing in the python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working Eclipse configuration to run **monkeyrunner** scripts can be found in this [post](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2012/03/eclipse-working-monkeyrunner.html) (with screenshots).